# Change Google maps v2 Language In Android native

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have checked all questions which are previously asked. I am rewriting this question because of i am unable see my preferred language on android's google map. I can set and get particular language in IOS google map but in android its not supported. In IOS google map shows its language region based. but in andorid its not showing.

Current i need gujarati language (OR region based). This is supported in web version and ios version of google map but not in andorid. Can any one guide me to do this in andorid?

I am setting google map's language via app locale.
Below is the code:

```
public static void setAppLocal(Context mContext) {
    GeneralFunctions generalFunc = new GeneralFunctions(mContext);
    String languageToLoad = "gu";
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    mContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
    mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem was reported in the Google issue tracker. You can find it here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150

I would suggest adding your comment in the public issue tracker and star this bug to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google. Hopefully, one day they will fix it.